# refresh Rails view data based on select_tag value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Rails view(mycontroller/index) with select_tag control.

I want to refresh it based on select_tag value, so if I change its value form will be refreshed with new values. How can I do that?

```
$(document).on 'ready page:load', ->
  $('#time').on "change", -> (
    value = $(this).val()
    $.ajax
      url: "my/_statistics?time=" + value
      type: "GET"
      success: (data) -> (
        #$('#_statistics').html(data)   if I'll comment this line it will work good
      alert data
  )
)
```

Comment: [AJAX](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the basics.  In coffee script, you'd do something like

```
$(document).on 'ready page:load', ->
  $('#select_field').on "change", ->
    value = $(this).val()
    # Use value to update your form
```